# How can I include a colon in a prepared statement?

Tags: php, pdo, prepared-statement

I've got the following query which works great when pasted into an SQL client but doesn't work when I'm executing it through PDO.

```
INSERT INTO mdt_order (`id`,`reference`,`customer_id`,`order_datetime`)
VALUES (NULL,'786d98e7','1960','2011-03-25 08:59:34')
```

I'm pretty sure it's the `:`'s in the date that are messing it up. The `order_datetime` field actually gets set to `2011-03-25 08??`

**How can I include colons in my PDO queries?**

Comment: What does your PHP look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Too bad I can't delete this accepted answer. Anyway, here is an edited answer:

> I'm pretty sure it's the :'s in the date that are messing it up.

I am pretty sure it is not.

However, to be *indeed* sure, one have to have an *error message* from PDO.

Answer (score 2):

I've never seen this behaviour. PDO ignores `':xyz'` syntax enclosed in SQL string quotes. You might have a buggy version though.

But anyway, if you are using prepared statements, then you really ought to be using bound parameters anyway:

```
$pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO mdt_order (`id`,`reference`,`customer_id`,`order_datetime`) VALUES (?,?,?,?)")
    ->execute(array(NULL, '786d98e7', '1960', '2011-03-25 08:59:34'));
```

If you want to keep using raw strings, then use [`->query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php) instead. This will never even attempt to look for :params, so avoid such problems.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "
    INSERT INTO
        mdt_order (`id`, `reference`, `customer_id`, `order_datetime`)
    VALUES
        (NULL, :reference, :customer_id, :order_datetime)";

$db = new PDO("mssql:host=sqlserver;dbname=database", "username", "password");

$statement = $db->prepare($query);

$parameters = array(
    ":reference" => $reference,
    ":customer_id" => $customer_id,
    ":order_datetime" => $order_datetime
);

$statement->execute($parameters);
```

Comment: Someone is upvoting all these irrelevant answers. Interesting.

Answer (score -1):

`:xyz` is named parameter in PDO.

That means if you use `pdo->prepare("SELECT :fields FROM :table :where");`

You can `statement->execute(array(":fields"=>$fields,":table"=>$table,":where"=>$where));`